# Evaluating all tournament scenarios

Tags: java, data-structures, branch, fork

I have an object `Tournament` that has a list of matches and each has the probability that player1 or player2 wins stored in a `Map<Player, Float>`. 
I iterate on the list of matches taking element `i` and `i + 1` to create a new match using their winners. The winner is chosen this way: if p1 (or p2) wins with a probability above a certain threshold, I pick it, otherwise I have to branch and evaluate both cases (case 1: p1 wins - case 2: p2 wins).
My goal is to create all possible scenarios and evaluate all possible tournament winners.
I am able to do it without branching (just recursively evaluate all match winners, until there is only the final match), but if I want all scenarios I don't really know how to do it.
Any ideas? Which data structure should I use? Is it possible to do something like C `fork` and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved using Monte Carlo method. I run the tournament many times (10k) and for each simulation the winner of each match is chosen according to his probability. Since I run it many times, I'm sure that I will encounter all possible scenarios (and I save them step by step, along with the predicted winner of the tournament).
It proved to be fast and effective, needing no additional data structure (just a set to save all scenarios and a map to save tournament winners with their probability).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do something like C fork and use it?

You can use an ExecutorService to submit any number of tasks. Assuming they are CPU bound you may want to use a fixed thread pool which is the size of `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for some kind of tree-browsing algorithm. You can use either [breadth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Using a recursion is basically using the latter one, but beware, it is quite common that the Java heap space is not enough, and you will eventually have to implement it on you own.

BFS and DFS are very similiar, they differ when it comes to using the data structure. BFS uses a queue, which is implemented by JSE's `LinkedList`, while DFS uses stack, implemented by `Stack` class.